# Is it possible to use Android mobile vision api to scan credit card info?

Tags: android-vision

I'm trying to adopt Android mobile vision API to scan credit cards inside my Android app (https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/android-mobile-vision-text-api.html?hl=sq)

Original developer blog post even mentions this use case.

However, it cannot recognize credit card number which typically has an embossed font.

Is it possible to provide extra params to narrow the search to increase recognition success?

Comment: Same here. It doesn't read credit card number but it reads all other information printed on the card. I think it doesn't recognize the font. https://www.card.io/ is an alternative. If you get any solution please share